# How to properly check and handle null values or objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

```
   var userDomain = (from a in this.db.DomainList.ToList()
                            join b in this.db.UserDomain.ToList() on a.DomainId equals b.UserDomainId
                            where b.UserId == new System.Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString())
                            select new
                            {
                                a.DomainId,
                                a.DomainName
                            }).FirstOrDefault();

string userDomainName = (userDomain.DomainName ?? "None").ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have the above sample code. When userDomain is null, i want to set userDomainName varibale to "None" else if userDomain is not null, userDomainName variable should be set to `userDomain.DomainName`

I have tried below line of code

```
 string userDomainName = (userDomain.DomainName ?? "None").ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but that does't work as it throws error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

if userDomain is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if `userDomain` is `null`, then

```
userDomain.DomainName
```

will fail.

In C# 6, you can get over this with the null conditional operator:

```
string userDomainName = userDomain?.DomainName ?? "None";
```

Before C# 6, you need:

```
string userDomainName = 
    (userDomain == null ? null : userDomain.DomainName) ?? "None";
```

That's assuming it's possilble for `userDomain` to be non-null and `userDomain.DomainName` to be null - if it's not, you could just use:

```
string userDomainName = userDomain == null ? "None" : userDomain.DomainName;
```

Note that you don't need the `ToString` part - calling `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` on a string will never change it.